# Insert filtered values into a table without spill error

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, office365, excel-tables

Column A below contains numbers 1-9 some of which are merged with empty cells.

I wish to filter out the blanks and normally would use the formula `=FILTER(A3:A15,A3:A15<>"")`.

This work great normally, but Because this produces a dynamic array when entered into a table this causes a spill error.

Can anyone think of way clean way around this? i.e. without hiding columns.  Normally I would use power query but this is only an example question of a much larger spreadsheet which I don't want to alter.

Using Power query would convert this to a table before outputting the actual table desired. Also, I do have multiple tables in this workbook and unless I can specifically turn off the 'Autofill' feature for a specific table this is also not feasible.

If you don't think its possible that's equally as useful. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Dynamic Array formulas will cause the `#SPILL!` error in a structured reference table. You should either put the outcome in a normal cell or use a pivot table to show the non-blank results in a column that will be dynamic.

Comment: Hi Terry, thanks. Yeah my solution is pretty much to have the output within normal cells as a filter and then have a table adjacent referencing the the neighbouring cell which it then automatically pulls down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a formula which will only output a single result and not an array.

For example

```
C2: =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER($A$1:$A$13,$A$1:$A$13<>""),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

and fill down.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any way, using formulas, to size the table so it is just the right size to encompass the entries in Column A.

[image]

Comment: Hey, yeah I thought this might be the case. The best I could do was to use the above formula, then have a table adjacent to this which referenced the first cell of the filtered output and automatically pulls down. works quite nicely (although I do hide the filtered column)